# How to send Verification/Confirmation Email when user have registered

Tags: php, email

I've written code about sending a verification mail to users who have registered !

But the thing is when i run the .php file in browser it says, not able to send the confirmation mail.

Someone told me that you need a server(domain) to send confirmation mail, it can't be sent using LOCALHOST.

Can i send confirmation mail from LOCALHOST ?? Any-way ??

If not, then tell me where can i get a **FREE** domain(for testing) where i can upload my .php files and send confirmation mail ??

Comment: Show the code you're using.  If you're just trying to use an SMTP server then you need to use an actual SMTP server.  If you're running one on your local machine then you can use that, though receiving servers may not accept the messages (potential spam).  You can use any SMTP server, though.  Gmail, for example.

Comment: What have you done so far? What OS? What Server? Say something na?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the script from a developer server at home, you're most likely having problems with your [ISP having blocked port 25](http://www.authsmtp.com/faqs/faq-4.html).

What I would recommend you to do is use a Transactional Email service such as:

- [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se/alpha-mail/)
- PostageApp
- Mandrill

Why?

- Has HTTP API support (runs on port 80/443, so no ISP blocking). I.e. easy to run from home.
- Future-proof. You don't have to think about hosting your own SMTP-infrastructure. Scaling it once your sendings increase.
- You don't have to think about delivery. Being blocked because the IP you are sending from isn't whitelisted, the list goes on.
- Statistics. Let's you track Total Sent/Clicks/Opens/Bounces.

How?

Since I am one of the developers behind AlphaMail, I of course recommend you to use it (but not only because I'm one of the developers behind it, but because it's great! :)). And since you're using PHP, it's easy to get going with the AlphaMail PHP-client:

```
include_once("comfirm.alphamail.client/emailservice.class.php");

$email_service = AlphaMailEmailService::create()
    ->setServiceUrl("http://api.amail.io/v1")
    ->setApiToken("YOUR-ACCOUNT-API-TOKEN-HERE");

$person = new stdClass();
$person->userId = "1234";
$person->firstName = "John";
$person->lastName = "Doe";
$person->dateOfBirth = 1975;

$response = $email_service->queue(EmailMessagePayload::create()
    ->setProjectId(12345) // Your AlphaMail project (determines template, options, etc)
    ->setSender(new EmailContact("Sender Company Name", "from@example.com"))
    ->setReceiver(new EmailContact("Joe Doe", "to@example.org"))
    ->setBodyObject($person) // Any serializable object
);
```

Another great thing with AlphaMail is that it separates logic from design. So you never have to bloat your code with ugly non-standard (email) HTML again. And once you need to change things it's no digging in code, just log into the AlphaMail Dashboard and edit your template immediately. Also, the templates are built using the simple template language [Comlang](http://docs.amail.io/?section=comlang), so they are highly personalizable.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Name:</b> <# payload.firstName " " payload.lastName #><br>
        <b>Date of Birth:</b> <# payload.dateOfBirth #><br>

        <# if (payload.userId != null) { #>
            <a href="/sign-up">Sign Up Free!</a>
        <# } else { #>
            <a href="/login?id=<# payload.userId #>">Sign In</a>
        <# } #>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendmail , smtp or some other services like Amazon SES . [Amazon Simple email service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)  provides sandbox feature with free of cost (but you need credit card to use its service) and it can easily configured into your localhost.